# Programmatically change the primary color used in several places in the CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass

The primary color of my Single Page Application is programmatically client-side defined. The problem is that is it used in many places in my code.

Eg. on load, I have (in SCSS):

```
body {
  background-color: #XXXXXX;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #XXXXXX;
}

.content ul li a {
  color: #XXXXXX;
  border: thin solid #XXXXXX;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #XXXXX;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

And I need to replace`#XXXXXX` to `#YYYYYY` everywhere, on the client side.

The different options I see are:

#### 1. isolate the color-related CSS, and wrap it with a class

Something like:

```
body {
  background-color: #XXXXXX;
  .btn-primary {
    background-color: #XXXXXX;
  }

  .content ul li a {
    color: #XXXXXX;
    border-color: #XXXXXX;
    &:hover {
      background-color: #XXXXX;
    }
  }

  &.other-color {
    background-color: #YYYYYY;
    .btn-primary {
      background-color: #YYYYYY;
    }

    .content ul li a {
      color: #YYYYYY;
      border-color: #YYYYYY;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #YYYYYY;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**+ Pro** It will eventually work

**- Con** Not DRY at all!

#### 2. Using a dirty JS that would inspect every occurences of `#XXXXXX` and replace with `#YYYYYY` in the DOM.

**+ Pro** Seems clean to me

**- Con** Not sure it is doable

#### 3. Using a dirty JS that would inspect every occurences of `#XXXXXX` and replace with `#YYYYYY` in the CSS file.

**+ Pro** Should do the job

**- Con** Not sure it is doable. And it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

#### 4. Compile several times the `application.css` to `application-other-color.css` and use it accordingly.

**+ Pro** Pretty easy to implement (compared to the other solutions)

**- Con** The user needs to load different assets, which is not optimum for a SPA

Has anyone faced this issue before? Is there any better solution than those two? If not, which one would you suggest? Did I miss some pros/cons?

Comment: If you are using SCSS, why don't you use variables?

Comment: @Oriol: Correct me if I'm wrong (I don't use Sass), but wouldn't that require recompiling it every time the user makes a request (i.e. #4), especially if the color is user-defined and can be arbitrary? Furthermore, the OP wants to do this on the client side, which probably means post-processing.

Comment: I'd rather go with @Oriol's suggestion and use SCSS, however another way of doing this is to use AJAX and have PHP recreate the CSS. Assuming the colour is an option that the client can make, when the select or whatever input type you are using is changed, you call the AJAX function which sends the new colour to the PHP script. The PHP script then populates the fields you need to populate with `#YYYYYY` and then you can include that php file in your page: `<body><?php include('myCSS.php');?>...` and reload the element the CSS applies to. If you're using a database, you can also store the pref.

Comment: (to continue my comment) or you can store it as a session variable or cookie and keep that setting across your webpages until the session or cookie is destroyed

Comment: Yes @BoltClock is right, the question relates to post-processed CSS, on the client side.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger as far as I know you only need to recompile css when you do some changes, anyway in the case you need to recompile everytime, you can cache the output for the css, shouldn't be hard to do, if you are really using scss you should use variables

Comment: @BoltClock I think you are right. Then, instead of SCSS variables, I think CSS variables are the perfect solution.

Comment: @Balder What you are saying is solution #4. But in a SPA (without page reload), this would result various dirty results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, #1, but I would structure it differently. It's best to separate these if they are indeed different states/classes, and name them semantically.

That way, if you decide, for example, that `.body-content--error` also needs to have green text, or whatever, you can easily edit it in. Now you just need to set the javascript to switch classes, which is simple.

This is actually very DRY code, in that `.body-content` and `.body-content--error` are different states of the same element. In fact, with the code below, you can set the class of `body` to `class="body-content body-content--error"` and inherit all of the `.body-content` CSS, and just change the `background-color` with `.body-content--error`.

```
$primary-color: #XXXXXX;
$error-color: #YYYYYY;

// Body content
.body-content {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.body-content--error {
  background-color: $error-color;
}

//Button (primary)
.btn-primary {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}
.btn-primary--error {
  background-color: $error-color;
}

// Links in the .content list
.content-list-link {
  color: $primary-color;
  border-color: $primary-color;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $primary-color;
  }
}
.content-list-link--error {
  color: $error-color;
  border-color: $error-color;
  &:hover {
    background-color: $error-color;
  }
}
```

Comment: OP mentions that the color is set client side, so Sass / preprocessor variables won't work.

Comment: If that is the case, then I would give every element that would be changed a `.user-chosen-color` class, and then use javascript to either change all of those elements' color, or append a `<style>.user-chosen-color{color:#YYYYYY}</style>` to the body, or something.

Answer (score 4):

[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) seem the perfect solution:

```css
body {
  --my-color: red;                   /* Set some value */
  background-color: var(--my-color); /* Use the value in the variable */
}
.btn-primary {
  background-color: var(--my-color); /* Use the inherited value */
}
```

Then, changing the colors is simple:

```css
document.body.style.setProperty('--my-color', newColor);
```

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  var rndcolor = '#' + ('00000' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 256 * 256 * 256).toString(16)).slice(-6);
  document.body.style.setProperty('--my-color', rndcolor);
};
```

```css
body {
  --my-color: red;
  background-color: var(--my-color);
}
.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.btn-primary {
  background-color: var(--my-color);
}
.content a {
  color: var(--mycolor);
  border: thin solid var(--my-color);
}
.content a:hover {
  background-color: var(--my-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <button class="btn-primary">Click me to change color</button>
  <a>I have a border</a>
</div>
```

The problem is that CSS variables are not widely supported yet.

Comment: It would be perfect! But "not widely supported yet" is a very cute euphemism : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables :)

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger I hope it will improve. According to [modern.ie](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/cssvariables/?filter=f3e0000bf), CSS variables are in development by Chrome and Opera, and under consideration by IE. And Firefox has already shipped them.

Comment: For sure, they'll eventually be available: it is so usefull! But I can't affort to wait for this feature right now.

Answer (score 0):

The whole approach is described above thanks to @MattDiamant but for the records, here's the final solution I built, which I reckon is highly useful.

### TL;DR

I made a dynamic [mixin](http://sass-lang.com/guide) which I simply need to call `@include variable-color($property-name);` and to change the `<body>` class to change `variable-color` everywhere.

### Explanations

I used `scss` and `erb`: the solution needs a preprocessor before SCSS, could be grunt, gulp, etc.

**If there is a 100% SCSS solution, I'd be curious to read about it.**

I have a Ruby hash of colors:

```
colors = {
  green: '#00FF00',
  blue: '#0000FF',
  red: '#FF0000'
}
```

In `_colors.css.scss.erb`, I have:

```
$default-background-color: #000000;

<% colors.each do |key, value|  %>
  <%= "$#{key}: #{value};" %>
<% end %>
```

which will output in `_colors.css.scss`:

```
$default-background-color: black;

$green = #00FF00;
$blue = #0000FF;
$red = #FF0000;
```

And further in `_colors.css.scss.erb`:

```
@mixin body-prefixed-rule($property, $class-name, $color) {
  body.#{$class-name} & {
    #{$property}: $color;
  }
}

@mixin variable-color($property) {
  #{$property}: $default-background-color; // Static default color, defined above
  <% colors.each do |key, value|  %>
    <%= "@include body-prefixed-rule($property, '#{key}', $#{key});" %>
  <% end %> 
}
```

The second mixin will output in `_colors.css.scss`:

```
@mixin variable-color($property) {
  #{property}: $default-background-color; // Static default color, defined above
  @include body-prefixed-rule($property, 'green', $green);
  @include body-prefixed-rule($property, 'blue', $blue);
  @include body-prefixed-rule($property, 'red', $red);
}
```

So in `application.css.scss`, I have:

```
@import '_colors';

button {
  color: white;
  @include variable-color('background-color');

  &:hover {
    background-color: white;
    @include variable-color('color');
  }
}
```

which finally outputs in SCSS without mixins:

```
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;

  body.green & {
    color: white;
    background-color: green;
  }
  body.blue & {
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
  }
  body.red & {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;

    body.green & {
      color: white;
      background-color: green;
    }
    body.blue & {
      color: white;
      background-color: blue;
    }
    body.red & {
      color: white;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

So I only need to change the class of my `<body>` to toggle background color everywhere, simply by using `@include variable-color($property-name);`